# Node js built-in modules not found in deployment using vercel ERROR: Could not resolve "crypto"

Tags: node.js, deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy a personal project which I made with express. I'm using passport as a way to authenticate and authorize the user, this library is using some of node js built-in modules like 'crypto' and 'http'. Everything works fine locally.

```
Build failed with 7 errors:
vc-file-system:node_modules/generaterr/index.js:2:19: ERROR: Could not resolve "util"
vc-file-system:node_modules/passport-local-mongoose/index.js:1:23: ERROR: Could not resolve "crypto"
vc-file-system:node_modules/passport-local-mongoose/lib/pbkdf2.js:1:23: ERROR: Could not resolve "crypto"
vc-file-system:node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:5:19: ERROR: Could not resolve "util"
vc-file-system:node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:4:19: ERROR: Could not resolve "http"
```

I tried adding the missing depedencies into the package.json but nothing changed.

Comment: You need to add deployment details. Seems that `npm install` is missing on your deployment machine

Answer (score 0):

Since your computer and hosting service are using different OS.please make sure you installing node modules on host OS like put npm install command inside start command

```
"start" : "npm i && node app.js"
```

Comment: Hi!, thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, still doesn't work. What confused me even more is that I tried to deploy another project that have the same version of passport js and it deployed perfectly.